# How to compare character varying (varcar) to UUID in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Operator does not exist: character varying = uuid

Client id is UUId and should be why it is not working.

Where I am wrong, since I have tried almost everything I imagined.

```
SELECT * FROM "cobranca_assinatura"
INNER JOIN "cadastro_cliente" ON ("cobranca_assinatura"."cliente_id" = "cadastro_cliente"."id")
WHERE "cadastro_cliente"."nome" LIKE marcelo% ESCAPE '\'
```

> [2019-03-21 14:40:34] [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist:
>   character varying = uuid [2019-03-21 14:40:34] 
>   Dica: No operator
>   matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add
>   explicit type casts.

Comment: What are the data types of `"cadastro_cliente"."id"`? and `"cobranca_assinatura"."cliente_id"`?

Comment: Tamer. Is uuid.

Comment: "cobranca_assinatura"."cliente_id" is Varchar

Comment: That's it, and the error is self-explanatory. You are comparing two different data types, must cast one type to the other before comparing.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

uuid is a specific datatype. To you it looks like text, but it's not. You cannot compare uuid using string functions `(uuid like "abc%")`, or compare it with text.

As Tamer suggests, you can cast it first, if you need to compare.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT 'A0EEBC99-9C0B-4EF8-BB6D-6BB9BD380A11'::uuid as my_uuid) foo 
WHERE my_uuid::text like 'a%'
```

For example, above I create a uuid by casting a string to uuid type. (You'll fail if you attempt to cast just any old string to uuid because 'abc' **cannot** be a uuid).

Then with a uuid item called 'my_uuid', I cast to back to a string to use string comparison. (Note the 'A' becomes 'a'!)

Comment: Showing how to cast it for comparing would make this a proper answer.

Comment: While this answer is acceptable and did help, it would be more beneficial to others to give a breakdown of the query you provided above on how you utilised casting

Comment: Yes, @Oozeerally. I am a newbie.And while I am practicing queries i was encountered with the same issue.But I was not able to understand this, so I am again researching this answer to know in detail.

Comment: @Himabindu I added answer below, If you are using java this may help you to understand easily.

Comment: This is actually a bad example for those who just want to understand simple, common cases. All you have to do is add `::text` to the name of the uuid column: `select * from some_table where uuid_col::text like '%b3b788%'`.

Answer (score 4):

In java -> spring boot for JDBC template. I got the same issue. This is type-mismatch error, it's expecting UUID datatype but supplying String.
So, I converted UUID from String using UUID.fromString() and using UUID type in prepared statement (SQL)

Example:

```
String testSelectQry = "SELECT * from facility_announcements where id=:announcementID";
SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource("announcementID", UUID.fromString("094b76da-4140-11eb-b139-0242ac11000f"));
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(testSelectQry, params, new FacilityAnnouncementMapper());
```

Comment: When adding the UUID into the prepared statement use below way
`preparedStatement.setObject(columnIndex++, UUID.fromString(payload.getIncommingUUID()));`

Answer (score 0):

as an option you might have added

```
 "?stringtype=unspecified"
```

to the JDBC URL.

So, in case you use jdbc placeholders as strings, it will convert it without throwing

```
operator does not exist: uuid = character varying
```